# Should I use a hyphen?

Tags: hyphens

Should a hyphen be used for "cost efficiency" in the below examples? Thank you.

> the cost-efficiency targets

> a cost-efficiency program

Comment: Have you googled the phrase to see whether a hyphen is typically used?

Comment: Yes. I have seen both uses, so not conclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both examples are compound modifiers of a third noun, *targets* and *program*.

This is the generally accepted use of hyphens for compound modifiers: when two nouns (or other words) are turned into an combined adjective that  modifies a third noun. The hyphen makes it clear that neither word alone is modifying the third word.

One time a hyphen is not used is when one of the words is an -ly ending adverb used in an adjectival way: "a rapidly accelerating train" is not hyphenated, but "a just-painted train" is.

Comment: You hyphenated "a just-painted train", so presumably you'd also hyphenate "a very-tired swimmer", right?

Comment: The hyphen is used to reduce ambiguity (the clarity mentioned in the answer), I consider the hyphen in "a very-tired swimmer" optional (read: I would omit it). The OP uses " the cost-efficiency targets" which, without context, *does* have ambiguity. Without a hyphen "targets" could be a verb or a plural noun. Hyphen could be omitted in the OP's second example as there is no interpretive risk.

Comment: Agreed! It really is all about reducing ambiguity, making comprehension easier.